# I clicked on a suspicious link with cross site scripting vulnerability

Tags: virus

I clicked on a suspicious link with cross site scripting vulnerability. Redirected me to youtube's home page. Anything I can do right now?

Comment: Maybe post the link here so we can see what exactly the link does.  Also force logout of all of your devices (at the site where the link leaded before the redirect to yt) (often you can find this Option somewhere in your Account settings) since he probably stole your session cookies.

Comment: this is the link: http://tiktok.tvaichi.sbs/P2xfhiL 
as for "at the site where the link leaded before the redirect to yt", I clicked the link and it kinda just sent me right to YouTube. There wasn't time in-between to see another site load. I signed out of YouTube though and changed my password. Also haven't opened up YouTube on my pc since I clicked that link.

Comment: We can't do a site analysis for you, so we can't give you any specific advice about what might have happened to your device. You can use tools like Cuckoo.ee to analyse it for you so see how bad it is.